Where's the error in the evaluation of $ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log x - x^{x} + 1}{\log x - x + 1} $?
I meet a limit, it is
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\log x - x^{x} + 1}{\log x - x + 1}
\end{align*}
First, let $ x = t + 1 $,then I use Taylor series
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log (1 + t) - (t + 1)^{t + 1} + 1}{\log (1 + t) - t} & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log (1 + t) - \exp\left[ (t + 1) \log (1 + t) \right] + 1}{\log (1 + t) - t} \\
 & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\log (1 + t) - 1 - (t + 1)\log (1 + t) + 1}{\log (1 + t) - t} \\
 & = \lim_{t \to 0} - \frac{t\log(1 + t)}{\log (1 + t) - t} \\
 & = \lim_{t \to 0} - \frac{t \cdot t}{t - t^{2}/2 - t} \\
 & = 2
\end{align*}
But use Desmos to draw a picture, I know that limit is 3.
What's wrong with me? And how to use Taylor series in a correct way?

You need to keep $O(t^2)$ terms in the numerator, which includes $[(1+t)\log(1+t)]^2/2$

Does log have base 10? In this case i got answer 1

Oh, i understood, it is ln(x). So, just Lopital's rule twice

@average_buffaloway_enjoyer Sorry, I copy with a book which in 1930.

@average_buffaloway_enjoyer Using L’Hospital’s rule (almost) always gives you the answer of that kind of limit, and for me trying it with other ways and using L’hospital’s rule just for test seems better!

@RDK these kind of limits are meant to be solved using Taylor expansion and it's not true that using L'Hopital's rule is almost always the best strategy

@SineoftheTime Well, that’s what I was about to say! I said ‘gives the answer’, not ‘gives the better intuition.’ :)

You have neglected a term in the expansion of $\exp((1+t)\log(1+t))$; in fact:
$$\exp((1+t)\log(1+t))\sim 1+(1+t)\log(1+t)+\frac{1}{2}(1+t)^2 (\log (1+t))^2.$$
At the numerator you're left with:
$$-t\log(1+t)-\frac12(1+t)^2 (\log (1+t))^2 \sim-t^2-\frac 12t^2=-\frac32t^2.$$

You didn't expand correctly, we have by Taylor
$$\frac{\log (1 + t) - e^{\left[ (t + 1) \log (1 + t) \right]} + 1}{\log (1 + t) - t}
=\frac{t-\frac {t^2}{2}+o(t^2)-e^{t+\frac {t^2}{2}+o(t^2)}+1}{-\frac {t^2}{2}+o(t^2)}=$$
$$=\frac{t-\frac {t^2}{2}+o(t^2)-1-t-t^2+o(t^2)+\frac {t^3}{6}+1}{-\frac {t^2}{2}+o(t^2)}=\frac{-\frac32t^2+o(t^2)}{-\frac {t^2}{2}+o(t^2)}=\frac{3+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to 3$$
Note that you should always include the remainder term (little-o or Big-O) in the series expansions to avoid such kind of confusion.
